# Blockchain programming books C#?

Tags: development, bitcoin-literature

**EDIT 1:**

It seems that what I really want to learn is how to create software which makes use of a distributed hash table.

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I want to learn about coding my own blockchain based software using the C# programming language. Do books exist yet which I could buy to learn about blockchain programming?

The blockchain idea/technology is absolutely unbelievably amazing, and I want to learn how to create blockchain based software.

Please understand, that I am not asking about a book which helps me interact with the bitcoin blockchain.  I want to know how to create distributed software using blockchain type technology.

Hats off to Satoshi Nakamoto for giving the world the blockchain idea.

Answer (score 8):

I just published a book about it. It's called ["Blockchain Programming in C#"](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=926087.0).

If you're looking for tools written in C#, you should try [NBitcoin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NBitcoin/). You can also find [the project on GitHub](https://github.com/NicolasDorier/NBitcoin).

I've also written lots of articles about it:

- Intro: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/768412/NBitcoin-The-most-complete-Bitcoin-port-Part-Crypt
- Stealth Payment, and BIP38: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/775226/NBitcoin-Cryptography-Part
- How to build transactions: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/835098/NBitcoin-Build-Them-All
- Using the NBitcoin Indexer: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819567/NBitcoin-Indexer-A-scalable-and-fault-tolerant-blo
- How to Scan the blockchain: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/784519/NBitcoin-How-to-scan-the-Blockchain (You can dismiss the ScanState for that, now I concentrate on the indexer)

Comment: Fantastic!  Thanks for all the effort in making these resources.

Comment: NBitcoin is a great library. It helps me to work with blockchain on C# much easier.

Answer (score 6):

A great way to start programming blockchain-based apps in C# is [BitcoinLib](https://github.com/GeorgeKimionis/BitcoinLib), which also comes with a [test console app](https://github.com/GeorgeKimionis/BitcoinLib/tree/master/ConsoleClient) that demonstrates how you can build a blockchain app in a few lines of code.

Repo: https://github.com/GeorgeKimionis/BitcoinLib

Some of its features are:

- Fully compatible and up-to-date with Bitcoin 0.9.3 RPC API.
- Design-by-contract, service-oriented architecture.
- Strongly-typed structures for complex RPC requests and responses.
- Implicit JSON casting for all RPC messages.
- Extended methods for every-day scenarios where the built-in methods fall short.
- Exposure of all RPC API's functionality as well as the extended methods through a single interface.
- Fallback mechanism for timed-out RPC requests.
- Custom RPC exceptions.
- Supports all Bitcoin clones.
- Can operate on unlimited daemons with a single library reference.
- Litecoin and Dogecoin integrations included.
- Each coin instance can be fully parametrized at run-time and implement its own constants.
- Console test client with demo methods implemented in it.
- Disconnected raw RPC connector included for quick'n'dirty debugging.
- Testnet ready.
- MONO compatible.
- Blockchain.info compatible.
- Fully configurable.

Answer (score 3):

An opensource book about to be released and I am finding very enjoyable is

Mastering bitcoin - Andreas M. Antonopoulos

available at https://github.com/aantonop/bitcoinbook

First two chapters are more introductory, later on he gets into a lot more detail. It will be published in December if you prefer paper.