# Which book would you recommend to learn Bitcoin programming?

Tags: bitcoin-literature

> There are three books I'm aware of for learning Bitcoin programming:
> Mastering Bitcoin (2nd edition) by Andreas Antonopoulos, Programming
> Bitcoin by Jimmy Song and Grokking Bitcoin by Kalle Rosenbaum. Which
> would you recommend?
>
> I'm a junior full stack web developer.

This question was asked by Hasan Hasan.

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/44322/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/18461/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/32462/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/4913/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/16/5406

Comment: This question is a bit problematic since it is essentially requesting a review of specific books. A question should always outline the problem it is trying to solve and then ask  _openly and timelessly_ for a solution. Since your answer would be a great fit for https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/18461 with only minor edits, I've decided to merge your answer into that.